# Not rendering &amp symbol in html from backend data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I had created a project on express handlebars which fetches some data from youtube API but the data had some special characters like &39# ( ***'*** symbol) &amp ( ***&*** symbol) in the title
Whenever I am rendering some data using handlebars, It is rendering the title as it is

SENDING DATA FROM  Backend

```
router.get("/demo", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("demo", {
    data:
      "Smith  &amp; Jone&#39; Car ",   // simply means Smith & Jone's Car
  });
});
```

RENDERING DATA VIA HANDLEBARS

```
<div class="bg-white container2 px-3 py-1">
    <a href="#">
        {{data}}    
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to official docs from handlebars

use `{{{data}}}`

instead of

```
<div class="bg-white container2 px-3 py-1">
    <a href="#">
        {{data}}    
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can we use partials instead?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<div class="bg-white container2 px-3 py-1">
    <a href="#">
        {{{data}}}
    </a>
</div>
```

instead